# Can't log in to Microsoft account on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

Today I installed Windows 10, everything went well and I can now use it normally. But I can't sign in to any applications that use the Microsoft account (Store, Mail, Calendar, ...) which causes some problems because I can't use those applications. Whenever I try to sign in to Microsoft account by clicking the option in a menu (be it selection of the service in Mail, connecting the User from Settings or downloading in Store), a window pops up for about a millisecond (where I presume I'd be asked for the account information) and then it instantly disappears. Can anyone help me?

I have tried looking elsewhere (even second page of Google) but they always talked about forgetting one's password or being blocked, but they didn't talk about not even having the chance to sing in.

Comment: do you use 2-factor authentication by chance?

Comment: can you screenshot that windows an upload it here?

Comment: @Ramhound No, I don't. I use the account for Hotmail. And I think 2-factory authentication wouldn't prevent the sign-in window from even showing prior to entering my credentials.

Comment: @Botmaster As I said, the window, where I presume I should write my credentials, disappears right after appearing. Sort of blinks in and out of existence. It's too fast to screenshot

Comment: you can try to contact microsoft support desk "support.microsoft.com and let them remote into your system and find the solution in case you didnt get a good answer here

Comment: @FilipSmola Reset Internet Explorer and try login again ?

Comment: Hotmail is a Microsoft Account; 2-favor authentication wouldn't block it but it would require an application password possibly.  it's not clear if you linked your local account to your MSA or not

Comment: @Ramhound No. I never logged in to the account outside of Google Chrome for the email. Because it doesn't let me even see the login form window.